# I want to have three columns in Wordpress foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, html-table

Here is my code it creates column after column I want to break after 3 columns. (I'm new to wp codes).

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <?php 
            $posts = get_posts('category=3&numberposts=10'); 
            foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
                <td width="150">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  ?>
                        <a target="_parent"> <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(200,100)); ?></a>
                    }?>
                    <a target="_parent"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'event_startEvent Start', true ); ?> 
                </td>

         <?php } ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by change this part of code

```
<?php 
     $posts = get_posts('category=3&numberposts=10'); 
      foreach($posts as $post) { 
 ?>
```

To

```
<?php 
        $count = 1;
        $posts = get_posts('category=3&numberposts=10'); 
        foreach($posts as $post) { 

         if($count == 4){
            echo '</tr><tr>';
            $count = 0; 
         }
         $count++;

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table>
    <?php 
        $posts = get_posts('category=3&numberposts=10'); 
        $colCount = 0;
        foreach($posts as $post) { 
            if ($colCount == 0 ) echo '<tr>';
            echo '
                <td width="150">
                    <a target="_parent"> 
                        '.( has_post_thumbnail() ? /* check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it. */
                            set_post_thumbnail_size( 200, 100 ) :
                            the_post_thumbnail()).'
                    </a>
                    <a target="_parent">'. the_title() .'</a>
                    '.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'event_startEvent Start', true ).'
                </td>';
            $colCount++;
            if ($colCount > 2) {
                echo '</tr>';
                $colCount = 0;
            }
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

It's better to concatenate HTML within a single php tag (whenever it's possible), than to open and close a php tag for every small piece of code you need to execute.

Also, your HTML is broken:

1. Your `<a>` tags should be like this:

   ```
   <a target="_parent">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not answer your question, because you really want to use table, but have you considered list?

```
<ul id="theList">
   <li><img /><a href="#">The title</a></li>
   <li><img /><a href="#">The title</a></li>
   <li><img /><a href="#">The title</a></li>
   <li><img /><a href="#">The title</a></li>
   <li><img /><a href="#">The title</a></li>
   <li><img /><a href="#">The title</a></li>
   <li><img /><a href="#">The title</a></li>
</ul>

<style>
#theList {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 450px; // more if <li> has padding
}
#theList li {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}
</style>
```